# html video does not pause if the command is in a if statement

Tags: html, function, if-statement, video, pause

I want to pause a video that is playing from inside an if statement in a funciton. it doesnt pause it till after every thing in the if has completed. if I move the pause outside the if , it does stop. I tried just about everything i can think of. an anyone explain to me why this is not working. and or provide a sample of working code?

```
function checktimeout()
    {
        seconds =seconds -1
        //video = document.getElementById('thisvideo');
        //video.pause()
        if (seconds == 0)
            {

                video = document.getElementById('thisvideo');
                video.pause()

                //do some other stuff here

            } 
    }


    seconds = 5
    delaytimer = setInterval(checktimeout,1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"I want to pause a video that is playing, with code from inside an IF statement of a function"*

See if the example below helps you in some way. I also added a boolean `needTimer` in case you want to stop using the timer after some condition (*eg: pause once and then never use timer again*). Ask anything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video id="thisvideo" controls  src="video.mp4" width="800" > </video>

<script>

var delaytimer; //# is updated by... function handle_Media_Events()
var needTimer = true;
var seconds = 5;

var myvideo = document.getElementById('thisvideo');

myvideo.addEventListener("play", handle_Media_Events );
myvideo.addEventListener("pause", handle_Media_Events );

function checktimeout()
{
    seconds -= 1; //# decrease by 1

    if (seconds <= 0) //# if SMALLER-THAN or EQUAL-TO
    {
        myvideo.pause();
        clearInterval(delaytimer); //# stop Timer
        needTimer = false; //# avoids re-adding Timer when another "play" event happens

        //# do some other stuff here...
        alert("video is now paused");
        seconds = 10; //set a new number (if still using... needTimer = true; )

    }
}

function handle_Media_Events()
{
    //# Handle Play/Pause events

    if( event.type == "play" )
    {
        //# start Timer if Play is is started
        if ( needTimer == true) { delaytimer = setInterval(checktimeout, 1000) };
    }

    else if( event.type == "pause" )
    {
        //# do whatever stuff when video is paused 

    }
}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: still the same result, but ill give ya credit, I didn't even think about adding an event listener. I did narrow this down a bit more, there is one function call I use to do some image matching and that is the one that does take a while to process, but I need the video to pause before this function is run. I also noticed if I put an alert right before this function call, the video does pause.

Comment: **(1)** What happens if you set `myvideo.pause(); clearInterval(delaytimer); doMyMachingFunction();` then the matching function itself can restart the timer on its last line of instructions. **(2)** Alternatively, you could just pause the video, then in the _"pause"_ event listener, you stop the timer and then trigger your image matching function. Again restart timer after matching code is finished.

Comment: well , I don't need to reset the counter after I pause the video. just need the video to pause right before the matching function. i added an alert box right before the matching funciton , which forces the video to pause , but i dont want the end user to have to click every time i run this matching function.